# How to align profile tab in top in my home page with flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, web, layout

I'm coding a layout like homepage from Linkedin, Twitter, etc ([example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeMwh.png)) with Flutter for Web, but the Profile Tab it's not fixing on top of layout. I need something like gravity property (Android), I tried usign Align class, CrossAxisAlignment, MainAxisAlignment but it didn't work. Also I tried to set a margin/padding subtracting the height of the context with container, but it didn't work either

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 50, right: 50),
            child: Row(children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 50),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        ),
                        child: Center(child: Text('Trend Stories')))
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 50),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        ),
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        child: Center(child: Text('Trend Stories')))
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        ),
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        child: Center(child: Text('Trend Stories')))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ])));
```

`code`

Comment: Try setting `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` in the `Row` widget

Comment: Thank you! It worked just fine!